# Make my webpage non-cacheable

Tags: apache, html, http-headers

I have been trying to make my webpage non-cacheable using HTTP Meta tags
This is the meta tags that i have written in my HTML page.

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"
```

When I analyze my packets through wireshark, I get HTTP 200 message for the first time. 
But when i extract the page second time, it gives me a HTTP 304 message which I assume means that the webpage is cached.

Can anyone please help me how to make my webpage non-cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

Use an .htaccess file. Create an .htaccess with the following content or add the following to the end of an existing .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Did I miss the word "Apache" in the question? Where did you see it?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code that you have sent exactly. but it doesn't work. is there anything that i need to edit in your code for .htaccess that you have posted above? please let me know. or do i have add the location of the .htaccess which is in /var/www to any html file?

Comment: hi fyodor, it indeed is apache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `<HEAD></HEAD>` section:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: Doesnt work Matthew. I have tried it. it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

These tags only affect what the browser does, not the server.

In order to control caching on the server, you should configure your web server and/or your web application, and I cannot help you with that without knowing what they are.

Comment: Hi Fyodor, it is a apache web server. and i want a web page which is non-cacheable. which means no matter how many times i access the web page it should always give me 200 status. not 304.